# Named function parameters break type inference for a closure assignment

Tags: swift, closures

I'm trying to assign two different methods (same signature) of a class to a variable to be executed later, but the assignment breaks when a method has named parameters. I feel like this might be some sort of bug, but don't want to be that naive. Here is the most simple example:

```swift
class ClassA {
    func foo(_ bool1: Bool, _ bool2: Bool) {
        print("foo")
    }

    func bar(_ bool1: Bool, bool2: Bool) {
        print("bar")
    }
}

let myFunc: (ClassA) -> (Bool, Bool) -> Void
//myFunc = { c in ClassA.foo(c) } // fine
myFunc = { c in ClassA.bar(c) } // Cannot assign value of type '(ClassA) -> (Bool, Bool) -> ()' to type '(ClassA) -> (Bool, Bool) -> Void'
```

I looked to this implemented evolution proposal on [SE-0110 distinguishing between single tuple and multiple argument types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md) for some tips, but couldn't come up with much. I also tried many variations of parentheses.

---

Swift version 5.0, Xcode 10.2.1

Comment: An interesting behavior, and I also think it as a bug. You may have tried, but this works `myFunc = { c in ClassA.bar(_:bool2:)(c) }`, as well as this `myFunc = ClassA.bar`, really odd.

Comment: I didn't come up with that latter solution which is probably what I should have done from the start! Thanks!

Comment: Filed a bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10847

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing that! I'll get it next time :)